# Is there any way to display a taxonomy sorted by another taxonomy?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I'm working on a homepage for a student paper and I'm needing some way to display 3-4 arbitrary pieces of content from each section every week (I.e., top stories) in a panel for each section.

In order to do this, I'm thinking I'll use the Weight module to create a list of top stories for the week via that Taxonomy, **which I would then like to group by another taxonomy term, "section".**

How would I go about doing this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a view that grouped row by the section taxonomy field, then sorted by sticky. Didn't even have to use Weight or Flag!

Oh, Views -- you make life so easy...

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the Flag module.  With it, you could flag certain content and then use Views to show just that content. You could also create different flags for different sections, etc.

Comment: Hi! It's an interesting idea, but the content already has a taxonomy for section attached; it doesn't make much sense to do sections as flags, unless I'm missing something. Why would this be better than using taxonomies?

Comment: You can certainly use both.  In this case, you could think of flags as custom/arbitrary "promote to home page" toggles.  An editor could go to content and "flag" it, and then it would show up in these lists on your homepages of your students.  These lists could be filtered to only flagged content and could be sorted by the flag time, and paged to 3 or 4, and then the first (or last) 3 or 4 would show up on the homepage automagically.  Or you could sort them any other way you wanted, too.